# How can we slow down render method speed in libGdx?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, render

I am new in the programming world, trying to code small scale games using libGDX. I want to know that if we can slow down the render method speed? E.g. render method runs around 60 times in a minute. Can we code like that render method run around 30 times in a minute or 10 times in a minute or 100 times in a minute etc? Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to slow your frame rate down? Is this related to my answer on your other question regarding your missile having different speeds at different frame rates? If so, and you are trying to get velocities to be constant by forcing your game to run at a slower frame rate, that is probably not a good idea because older slower devices still might run slower than what you set it at. You want your game to run independently of the frame rate so that if any unexpected problems come up your game will handle it, which is where using delta time comes in like I mentioned in your other question.

Answer (score 0):

> render method runs around 60 times in a minute

60 times per *second* is quite normal but 60 times per *minute* is definetely **not** normal.

---

Assuming you create a desktop application, you can specify the framerate in your `DesktopLauncher`.

To do this, you can simply seg the field [foregroundFPS](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/LwjglApplicationConfiguration.html#foregroundFPS) in your launch configuration.

For example, it could like that(I modified the code from [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Starter-classes-and-configuration#desktop-lwjgl)):

```java
package com.me.mygdxgame;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.foregroundFPS=10;
        new LwjglApplication(new MyGdxGame(), cfg);
    }
}
```

However, this is an integer specifying how often render() is called per second.

If you want it to be called slower than once per second, you would need to use something like `Thread.sleep();` inside the render() method.

However, you program won't respond until this time has finished.

This may be ok in development when debugging/testing something but is is a big problem in production

If you want your game to react quickly and run some code e.g. once per minute, you may consider using a background thread(pool) or a Timer (or similar).

If you want to know how multithreading works with LibGdX, you may take a look at [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Threading).

You can basically use Threads normally (except with HTML) but you should use `Gdx.app.postRunnable();` in order to make UI changes(like `Platform.runLater();` in JavaFX).